# Efficiently searching a pair of ordered lists with noise

Tags: python, algorithm, search

Assuming two data sets are in order and that they contain pairwise matches, **what is an efficient way to discover the pairs**? There can be noise in either list.

From sets A,B the set C will consist of pairs (A[X<sup>1</sup>],B[Y<sup>1</sup>]),(A[X<sup>2</sup>],B[Y<sup>2</sup>]),...,(A[X<sup>n</sup>],B[Y<sup>n</sup>]) such that X<sup>1</sup> < X<sup>2</sup> < ... < X<sup>n</sup> and Y<sup>1</sup> < Y<sup>2</sup> < ... < Y<sup>n</sup>.

The problem can be demonstrated with the simplified Python block, where the *specifics of how a successful pair is validated is irrelevant.
Because the validation condition is irrelevant*, the condition return_pairs(A, B, validate) == return_pairs(B, A, validate) is not required to hold, given that the data in A,B need not be the same, just that there must exist a *validation function for (A[x],B[y])*

```
A = [0,0,0,1,2,0,3,4,0,5,6,0,7,0,0,8,0,0,9]
B = [1,2,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,4,0,5,6,0,0,7,0,0,8,0,9]
B1 = [1,2,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,4,0,5,6,0,0,7,7,7,0,0,8,0,9]

def validate(a,b):
  return a and b and a==b

def return_pairs(A,B, validation):
  ret = []    
  x,y = 0,0    
  # Do loops and index changes...
    if validation(A[x], B[y]):
        ret.append((A[x], B[y]))
  return ret

assert zip(range(1,10), range(1,10)) == return_pairs(A,B,validate)
assert zip(range(1,10), range(1,10)) == return_pairs(A,B1,validate)
```

Comment: what's your question again?

Comment: Added bold formatting to the question.

Comment: How do you distinguish between the noise values and the desired ones? Is it a required condition that `return_pairs(A, B, validate) == return_pairs(B, A, validate)` ?

Comment: A lot of things are unclear.  What is a "matching pair"?  Does that mean a pair of indices i and j such that A[i] = B[j]?  The sentence beginning "From sets A,B" describes a set C which is... the desired answer?  But it seems it can't be that, since C could simply be *almost any* sequence of pairs, e.g. the pairs (A[1], B[1]), (A[2], B[2]), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating each list in two nested loops you can first remove the noise according to your own criteria, then create a third list with the filtered elements and run each item (being a newly formed tuple) of the list against your validation. This is assuming I understood the question correctly, which I think I didn't really:

#### [Demo](https://repl.it/COmQ)

```
A = [0,0,0,1,2,0,3,4,0,5,6,0,7,0,0,8,0,0,9]
B = [1,2,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,4,0,5,6,0,0,7,0,0,8,0,9]

def clean(oldList):
    newList = []
    for item in oldList:
        if 0<item and (not newList or item>newList[-1]):
            newList.append(item)
    return newList
    
def validate(C):
    for item in C:
        if item[0] != item[1]:
            return False
    return True

C = zip(clean(A),clean(B))

#clean(A):[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
#clean(B):[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
#list(C):[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6), (7, 7), (8, 8), (9, 9)]
#validate(C): True
```

Comment: This assumes that noise can be evaluated independent of the association between set A and set B, which is not the case. Noise is simply anything that fails to validate with the correct pairing in the associated data. The example used nonzero-equality to simplify the problem. The asked question is independent of the details inside A,B, and validate.

Comment: Well that's what you get when you don't make things clear enough for people like me, useless answers

Answer (score -1):

A solution. O(n<sup>2</sup>)

```
def return_pairs(A,B, validation):
  ret = []

  used_x, used_y = -1,-1
  for x, _x in enumerate(A):
    for y, _y in enumerate(B):
        if x <= used_x or y <= used_y:
            continue
        if validation(A[x], B[y]):
            used_x,used_y = x,y
            ret.append((A[x], B[y]))
  return ret
```

Comment: If this is an (approximate) answer, then your problem is equivalent to finding the longest common subsequence (LCS) between two strings, but with weights for each match.  This can be solved *optimally* in O(n^2) using dynamic programming.